# How to import data into hive table with date format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss UTC?

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, timezone, data-science, hiveql

How to import data into hive table with date format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss UTC`? I have data in CSV format with date in the format `2019-11-01 00:00:02 UTC` I tried to use below command, however the table data still shows as null.

Typical row of CSV:

```
2019-11-01 00:00:02 UTC,view,5802432,1487580009286598681,,,0.32,562076640,09fafd6c

--ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp.formats"="yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");,
```

Comment: Why do you use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` when the data isn't in that format? There's no T and there's a timezone at the end.

Comment: I used this and it fixed the issue


ALTER TABLE table_name SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp.formats"="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");